# ActiveDirectory2 and Paging

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/activedirectory2 and I am making a query that is returning elements greater than our page size allows (2000).

Does anyone have any clue how to page on the result set? There's no instructions on their page although they claim it is possible.

Or any other ideas of how to get all of my results?

```
var datelessQuery =  '&(employeeID=*)(!(employeeID=service))(!(employeeID=0))(mail=*))';

//Where do I ask for the next result???
ad.findUsers(datelessQuery, (err, users) => {
    if(err){
        QuickLog('ERROR: ' + JSON.stringify(err)); 
        return;
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested...

I skipped paging altogether. Instead, luckily, I was able to query based on the alphabet. At my job I have a query limit of 2000, thankfully we only have x number of employees. So I am able to see that each query for each letter is less than 2000. This may be a problem in the future but hopefully paging is fixed by then.

Thanks